# Проблема с битыми пакетами. Debian 7.4

Tags: debian

Проблема заключается в "битых" пакетах.

При команде:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Выдаёт:

> Проблема заключается в "битых" пакетах.

При команде:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Выдаёт:

> **fp-ide-2.6.0 fp-units-base-2.6.0 fp-units-db-2.6.0 fp-units-fcl-2.6.0  fp-units-fv-2.6.0 fp-units-gfx-2.6.0
>   fp-units-gtk2-2.6.0 fp-units-math-2.6.0  fp-units-misc-2.6.0
>   fp-units-net-2.6.0 liba52-0.7.4-dev libatk1.0-dev  libavahi-client-dev
>   libavahi-common-dev libcaca-dev  libcairo-script-interpreter2
>   libdbus-1-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra  libflac-dev
>   libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev  libglib2.0-dev
>   libglu1-mesa-dev libice-dev libjpeg8-dev libmad0-dev  libmikmod2-dev
>   libmodplug-dev libogg-dev libpcre3-dev libpixman-1-dev  libpng12-dev
>   libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-dev 
>   libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libslang2-dev libsm-dev libsvga1 
>   libsvga1-dev libts-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev 
>   libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev 
>   libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev 
>   libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev mesa-common-dev
>   x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev 
>   x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
>   x11proto-randr-dev  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
>   x11proto-xinerama-dev  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev**

Прошу, помогите с этим!

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get update
```

после:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

теперь еще:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

И ребутнуть Ос. После пробовать.